# python typing: callback protocol and keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-typing, callable

For example, mypy accepts this:

```
class P(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: int)->int: ...

def call(a: int, f: P)->int:
    return f(a)

def add_one(a: int)->int:
    return a+1

call(1,add_one)
```

but not this:

```
class P(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: int, **kwargs: Any)->int: ...

def call(a: int, f: P)->int:
    return f(a)

def add_one(a: int)->int:
    return a+1

def add_one_and_b(a: int, b: int= 1)->int:
    return a+1+b

call(1,add_one)
call(1,add_one_and_b)
```

errors (same error for the last two lines):

```
error: Argument 2 to "call" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], int]"; expected "P"  [arg-type]
```

How can one specify the type "method that takes as argument an int, possibly keyword arguments; and returns an int" ? (with or without using Protocol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `Callable[[int], int]` is all you need.

---

Protocols specify things an object *definitely can* do. Not things it can't, or things it might be able to do.

You're trying to specify "takes as argument an int, possibly keyword arguments; and returns an int". The only thing you *definitely can do* with a callable like that is call it with an int, and get an int. If you want to use a protocol, that's what you should specify with your protocol:

```
class P(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: int, /)->int: ...
```

This is almost identical to your original protocol. The only thing I've changed is adding a `/` to mark all arguments before it positional-only. That doesn't mean your objects need to take a positional-only argument; it means that the protocol requires objects to support passing the argument positionally, but doesn't require objects to support passing it by any particular keyword name.

However, you don't need a custom protocol for this. `Callable` can specify this directly:

```
P = Callable[[int], int]
```

If you test this on the [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=19a5678478b33e5fabe5b297b4a5fa67):

```
from typing import Callable, Protocol

class P1(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: int, /) -> int: ...
P2 = Callable[[int], int]

def call1(a: int, f: P1) -> int:
    return f(a)

def call2(a: int, f: P2) -> int:
    return f(a)

def add_one(a: int) -> int:
    return a+1

def add_one_and_b(a: int, b: int= 1) -> int:
    return a+1+b

def add_one_with_different_arg_name(b: int) -> int:
    return b+1

call1(1,add_one)
call1(1,add_one_and_b)
call1(1, add_one_with_different_arg_name)

call2(1,add_one)
call2(1,add_one_and_b)
call2(1, add_one_with_different_arg_name)
```

you'll find that mypy reports no errors for any of the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your second protocol promises that `f` can take *arbitrary* keyword arguments; that's not true of either `add_one` or `add_one_and_b`. Suppose you wrote

```
def call(a: int, f: P)->int:
    return f(a, foo="blah blah blah")
```

Would you agree that `call(3, add_one)` should be rejected in this case? `add_one` will be called in a manner consistent with how you said `f` could be called, but it doesn't accept a keyword argument `foo`.

Answer (score -2):

did you try this:

```
class P(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: int, **kwargs: Any)->int: ...

def call(a: int, f: Protocol)->int:
    return f(a)
```